# Late to file S-Corp taxes in US

Tags: united-states, taxes, s-corporation

I have a small one person s-corp in USA. It's now almost first day of summer; however, I still haven't filed my corp taxes due to some personal issues. What do I do at this point? Should I just fill my taxes using TurboTax? What is the late fee?

Answer (score 2):

You should file ASAP. Penalties are pretty expensive: [$195 per month per shareholder](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1120s/ch01.html#d0e534). If you haven't paid, you'll also pay 0.5% per each month you're late, so if your tax is $1000, you'll be paying $200 per month until you file and pay (that's in addition to the regular interest on the late payment).

There are additional penalties for late filing of K-1, which may also be applicable. Also, if you're late on your payroll forms (and payments), you may be subject to much more severe "trust fund recovery" penalties.

Comment: I don't have any employees and don't file any payroll forms, so hopefully I am not a subject to more severe "trust fund recovery" penalties

Comment: @VladMiller what do you mean you don't? What about yourself?

Comment: I don't pay myself a salary; Should I?

Comment: Yes, you should. Officers of a corporation (any corporation) must be paid a *reasonable* salary. By not paying yourself salary, you're essentially evading payroll taxes, the IRS doesn't take it nicely. Get a tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in your State) to help you understand what the requirements are.

Comment: I would definitely find experienced CPA to help me. Is there any good article you can suggest me to read first?